# PHPUnit test method won't receive array as a paremeter

Tags: unit-testing, phpunit, tdd, laravel-8

I have a a PHPUnit test where the third method won't receive the array returned in the second method. Take a look:

```
<?php

namespace Tests\Unit;

use Tests\TestCase;

class TesteTest extends TestCase
{
    public function testFirst()
    {
        $test = ['id' => 123];
        $this->assertNotEmpty($test);
        return $test;
    }

    /** @depends testFirst */
    public function testSecond(array $test)
    {
        $this->assertNotEmpty($test);
    }

    /** @depends testSecond */
    public function testThird(array $test)
    {
        $this->assertNotEmpty($test);
    }
    
}
```

This the response I have from PHPUnit:

> Argument 1 passed to Tests\Unit\TesteTest::testThird() must be of the type array, null given, called in C:\Users\edgar\Documents\Projetos\Solarium\solarium-api\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\src\Framework\TestCase.php on line 1527

Any ideas of where I might be going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Idea is simple. [Check documentation](https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/9.5/writing-tests-for-phpunit.html).

> - A producer is a test method that yields its unit under test as return value.
> - A consumer is a test method that depends on one or more producers and their return values.

Your producer `testSecond` return nothing to your consumer `testThird`

```
public function testSecond(array $test)
{
    $this->assertNotEmpty($test);
    return $test;
}
```

Comment: I was intending to return the array that the method receives.

Comment: @EdgardBertelli   than return that array :) for now you return nothing from `testSecond`